# Sikuli IDE terminates without error message

Tags: windows, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm trying to record a Sikuli script from the IDE on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine. I start it from the batch file (as suggested from several support threads handling other issues) and when I try "take a screenshot" or to record a mouse action the Sikuli IDE vanishes and nothing more happens.

Checking running tasks it is shown that the Sikuli IDE process is still running.

(Version: Sikuli X r930)

Anyone experienced this?

(edit: added question)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by removing existing Java installations and installing Java 1.6.0_33.